# Mikrotik PPTP VPN - Adding automatically routes - safer alternatives

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, mikrotik-routeros

We have 5 Mikrotik routers connected with PPTP VPN. One is the server and the other 4 are clients. All of them have RouterOS v6.46.3 (stable).

Every time one PPTP breaks and reconnects I have to go to IP>Routes and update the "Gateway" option from unknown to "pptp-vpn" for the Route of this connection.

**Question 1:** Is there any way to set the routes automatically when the vpn reconnects?

**Question 2:** From my search online I saw that PPTP VPN is not safe and many recommend to avoid it. Which are my other options to replace these not safe VPNs?

***UPDATE:*** All devices have RouterOS v6.49.12 (stable) - apart from one that has DNS problem when I click "Download & Install" in the update page

Answer (score 0):

> All of them have RouterOS v6.46.3 (stable).

All of them ought to have v6.49.12 (stable).

> Question 1: Is there any way to set the routes automatically when the vpn reconnects?

Instead of defining routes through a specific interface directly, define them through the *IP address* that the client is assigned, and RouterOS will resolve them to the correct interface every time.

> Question 2: From my search online I saw that PPTP VPN is not safe and many recommend to avoid it. Which are my other options to replace these not safe VPNs?

For static site-to-site tunnels, WireGuard is commonly suggested (it is supported by RouterOS 7.x), but IPsec may offer better performance due to hardware acceleration – either a GRE tunnel over IPsec, or plain policy-based IPsec.

For roaming clients (PCs), IPsec using IKEv2 is the modern option (IKEv2 supports user-level authentication and so on), although routing additional networks through a roaming IPsec client can be troublesome, so it doesn't sound like it's the best choice for you specifically.

Otherwise, L2TP/IPsec is the most direct replacement (especially if you want to support old clients). It uses the same PPP as PPTP does, so it'll have very similar behavior, just better security.

WireGuard is also an okay choice for roaming clients – it lacks automatic configuration (you have to deploy static configs to each and every client), but it's very good at tracking network changes. There are no reconnections or disconnections in WireGuard.

RouterOS also supports OpenVPN, which would probably be suitable for all situations, but 1) you really need to upgrade RouterOS to get a ton of improvements within its OpenVPN support, 2) I've never used it *via RouterOS* myself so I can't comment on its capabilities much.

You can always have *more than one* VPN type, e.g. IKEv2 for normal roaming PCs and WireGuard for site-to-site tunnels.

Comment: they all except one have the v6.49.12 - I wrote on my question the wrong version. The config is simple, static site-to-site - I just want to connect the networks, I don't have roaming clients at all. Tried the OpenVPN but I had so many disconnects and the problem from question 1 was also there.

Comment: "define them through the IP address that the client is assigned"  do you mean on IP>Routes> to have the gateway 192.168.89.100 which is the IP of the client when it connects ?

Comment: would it be wise to use "on-up" script to add the Route when it connects??

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean – if the client gets the IP address 192.168.89.100, then you should be able to define a route via `gateway=192.168.89.100`, just like you'd do for an Ethernet connection, and the router will automatically know which interface to use. It seems a more clean approach than using on-up, to be honest.

Comment: From what I saw, the ip of the client can change. For example : vpn1 has .100 and vpn2 has .99. They both disconnect and if the vpn2 connects first will get the .100  and vpn1 will get the .99

Comment: You can define the addresses statically as part of the "PPP > Secrets > Remote Address" configuration for each client.

Comment: _(Now that I'm looking at it, apparently you can even define routes there, too? I'm not sure if that's what the field does, given that it doesn't seem to be a multi-value field and takes a 'string' value instead of a 'network prefix' value... but it might still be worth looking into)_